# Why is Django-lean test failing with "NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Tags: django

I'm confused why my tests won't pass for the Django-lean module.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser (django_lean.experiments.tests.test_tags.ExperimentTagsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lean-0.15-py2.7.egg/django_lean/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 55, in testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser
    client_factory=create_registered_user_client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lean-0.15-py2.7.egg/django_lean/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 71, in doTestIntegration
    response = client.get(confirm_human_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 290, in get
    response = self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 230, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 74, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 142, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/defaults.py", line 24, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({})))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/utils.py", line 29, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 125, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/utils.py", line 29, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 378, in render
    raise e
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1736.834s
```

Here is the test:
class ExperimentTagsTest(TestCase):
    urls = 'django_lean.experiments.tests.urls'

```
def setUp(self):
    self.experiment = Experiment(name="test_experiment")
    self.experiment.save()
    self.experiment.state = Experiment.ENABLED_STATE
    self.experiment.save()

    self.other_experiment = Experiment(name="other_test_experiment")
    self.other_experiment.save()
    self.other_experiment.state = Experiment.ENABLED_STATE
    self.other_experiment.save()
    self.mox = mox.Mox()


def testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser(self):
    def create_registered_user_client(i):
        user = User(username="user%s" % i, email="user%s@example.com" % i)
        user.set_password("password")
        user.save()

        client = Client()

        if not client.login(username=user.username, password="password"):
            raise Exception("login failure")
        return client
    self.doTestIntegration(
        url=reverse('django_lean.experiments.tests.views.experiment_test',
                    args=[self.experiment.name]),
        client_factory=create_registered_user_client)

def doTestIntegration(self, url, client_factory):
    confirm_human_url = reverse('django_lean.experiments.views.confirm_human')
    # confirm_human_url set to '/main-app/confirm_human/' during test
    found_control = False
    found_test = False
    for i in range(100):
        client = client_factory(i)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = client.get(confirm_human_url) # this is where the Client can't find the url
        self.assertEquals(204, response.status_code)
        response = client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)
        in_test = "test" in response.content.lower()
        in_control = "control" in response.content.lower()
        self.assertTrue(in_test != in_control)
        found_control = found_control or in_control
        found_test = found_test or in_test

    self.assertTrue(found_control)
    self.assertTrue(found_test)
```

This is the View, django_lean.experiments.views.confirm_human

```
@never_cache
def confirm_human(request):
    experiment_user = WebUser(request)
    experiment_user.confirm_human()
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Finally, this is the URL patterns from  django_lean.experiments.urls :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django_lean.experiments.views',  
    url(r'^goal/(?P<goal_name>.*)$', 'record_experiment_goal'), 
    url(r'^confirm_human/$', 'confirm_human')  
)
```

I don't understand why the client.get request can't be followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Couldn't find any reference to `opensearch` in Django-lean source. Are you using a Django opensearch plugin or is some other app referring to opensearch? Try searching for `opensearch` in your project.

**Original Answer**

At first blush it seems that one of the templates is using an `{% url %}` tag with argument `opensearch`. At least that is what I suspect based on the following lines in the error trace.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 378, in render
    raise e
```

I am not familiar with Django-lean but I think it will be worrh checking if they have an URL named `opensearch`.

Comment: Opensearch is used in the App.
I can reverse('opensearch') in the Python shell. However, in the test, reverse('opensearch')
*** NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.